# Chromium Kiosk ALMOST done

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, chromium, kiosk

I have a 12.04 system here with a chromium kiosk. I have it auto logging in and auto starting chromium kiosk mode and incognito to the proper web page. Only this is that we dont want people to be able to Alt+F4 or Ctrl+W out of chromium. Ive tried disable Alt+F4 in the keyboard shortcut keys and it does not work for some reason, however, disable Ctrl+Alt+Del does work (Which is good). So those are the last two things I need to figure out to make this Chromium Kiosk production ready. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a keyboard that does not have those keys? Otherwise I think those shortcuts are built into the code of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your kiosk browser is showing a page under your control, add some JS to that page to bind to the keydown event. In your event handler, check if the key(s) pressed match those you want to "block" - and if so call event.preventDefault(). This should stop the browser's default behaviour of closing/exiting.

e.g. (using jQuery):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 27) // if the key is ESC
        e.preventDefault(); // do nothing
});
```